# Google Oauth Authentication Problems

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am having a similar challenge

```html
The redirect URI in the request, http://kineticdev.ilearn.fun/google/oauth_authorized, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/267848996084-nigetbdmho0i2qrmjfkd070i1u3mjrdc.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=267848996084
```

I have defined my uri=http://kineticdev.ilearn.fun/google/oauth_authorized&scope=profile+email in the Google Oauth window but still having challenges

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured the challenge here. I had to search for Google+ API and enable it. This was a step I missed in the Google documentation